# C++ nested method try catch (practices)

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

I'm new to C++ (coming from C) and writing a class `B` that is a member of another class `A`.

The member `B` will throw an exception if the parent tries to access data that does not exist from `B`'s container (I throw an `invalid_argument` exception). The member `B` has an object that can be thought of like an STL container, so it will be for this example.

My question is: if I catch the original invalid_parameter exception in `A`, is it considered good C++ practice to re-throw the same exception (I'd re-throw the original error, but I do some logging in it, so the `what()` is different), or can I just throw `std::exception`. My code now has many

`try { A.calls_b_exception } catch (std::invalid_argument& ie) {...} catch (std::exception& e) {...}`

blocks and I was wondering if I could reduce them to

`try { A.calls_b_exception } catch (std::exception& e) {...}`

and still be following good C++ paradigms.
Example code that is similar to my situation:

```
class B
{
    std::vector<int> stuff;

    int get_value(int index)
    {
       if (index >= stuff.size()) {
            stringstream err;
            err << "--> invalid index " << index << " for stuff";
            throw std::invalid_argument(err.str());
        }
    }
}

class A
{
    B b;
    // Assume there are methods to add a bunch of stuff to B
    int get_value(int index) 
    {
        try {
            b.get_value();
        } catch (std::invalid_argument& ie) {
            stringstream err;
            err << ie.what() << "\n\t--> A::get_value(" << index << ")";
            // should I throw the same exception here or is this considered good C++ etiquette?
            throw std::exception(err.str());
        } catch (std::exception& e) {
            throw;    // something I was not anticipating handling happened
        }
    }
}

int main
{
    A a;
    // Assume more stuff to add to A
    try {
        a.get_value(-1);
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        stringstream err;
        err << "--> invalid index " << index << " for main";
        throw std::exception(err.str());exception here?
    }
}
```

Comment: Typo? Your "I do this" and "should I do this" are identical.

Comment: In the top-level exception handler, you don't actually *know* where the exception comes from or what it might be, unless the code in the `try` block is very narrow (like your single function call). I would personally also not catch an exception unless I actually handle the error, just rethrowing it with a more verbose error message is not "handling" the error, IMO.

Comment: `My code now has many: try { A.calls_b_exception } catch (std::invalid_argument& ie) {...} catch (std::exception& e) {...}` . you actually don't have to catch both if you only log them. `std::invalid_argument` inherits from `std::exception`. catching `std::exception` will also catch `std::invalid_argument` and you still can access the what() function. `try { A.calls_b_exception } catch (std::exception& e) {...}` is just fine.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I handle the error by terminating and printing the error in the end. I just didn't do so in this example for brevity as I was more concerned with the topic of if throwing a more general exception is good practice as long as the user would know why on runtime. My try blocks are narrow, so the only other exceptions I would expect would be unpredictable system exceptions that would also cause a prompt program exit.

Comment: @user1810087: I was aware of the inheritance, but I was unsure if it would be better to catch the specific exception in A and also have a more general catch in A as well for other possible exceptions (which I'll add in an edit).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit fixed, apologies for copy/paste without editing

Comment: Depending on the situation and whether you are using C++11 or newer, you may find [`std::nested_exception`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/nested_exception/) useful. **Edit:** just noticed the C++11 tag - my bad :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot instantiate `std::exception(std::string)`, so my initial approach will not work.
Thanks to those of you who took time to read through my question and help me out.